# Select query with join multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've 3 tables, `A, B` and `C`, with columns

```
UserId, CompanyId, Quantity, Rate
```

I want to do query which return results like this query below

```
SELECT 
    (A.Quantity + B.Quantity + C.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
    SUM(A.Quantity * A.Rate) + SUM(C.Quantity * C.Rate) AS TotalAmount, 
    TotalQuantity/TotalAmount AS Result 
FROM 
    A, B, C  
WHERE
    (A.UserId = 1 AND A.CompanyId = 1) 
    AND 
    (A.UserId = B.UserId AND A.UserId = C.UserId AND A.CompanyId = B.CompanyId 
     AND A.CompanyId = C.CpmpanyId)
```

I've tried to run this query but its not working the way it suppose to be. I'm missing some thing here. Kindly help me.

```
Table A 

UID    CID    Quantity  Rate
1       1      90        60
1       1      100        9


Table B

UID    CID    Quantity
1       1       100
1       1       50

Table C

UID    CID    Quantity  Rate
1       1       5        5
1       1       5        5
```

Comment: What output do you get? Is it an error or wrong output?

Comment: What is it doing? Is there an error? What is that error? Is the output not what you expect?  What are the specific inputs and outputs of this statement, and what did you expect?

Comment: wrong output, every item entry is showing twice.

Comment: its adding every thing twice! e.g if i have A.Quantity=100, its adding 200+B.Quantity

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @user2516394 This query, as it is, shouldn't even run on SQL server since you are not aggregating the columns use on `TotalQuantity`, and neither using a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Just try using Inner Join instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the query based on the edited question:

```
select sum(Quantity) TotalQuantity, sum(Quantity * Rate) TotalAmount, sum(Quantity) / sum(Quantity * Rate * 1.0) Result
from
(
   select UID, CID, Quantity, Rate
   from A
   union all
   select UID, CID, Quantity, 1 Rate
   from B
   union all
   select UID, CID, Quantity, Rate
   from C
) t
where
   t.UID = 1 
   and t.CID = 1
```

Also here is a [working example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bbad3/3)

Comment: +1, good to see that you changed the query to use proper explicit joins

Comment: i've total quantity=350, but why this query return 1400 in Total Quantity, same goes for Total Amount

Comment: Need to see the values that's available in A,B & C tables for UserId = 1 and CompanyId=1 to answer your comment.

Comment: I've only UserId, CompanyId & Quantity Field in Table B , is this the problem

Comment: When you are doing a division or an addition of numbers you need to handle nulls if there is a possibility that one of teh vlues coudl be null. This is not important if your table structure for these fields is not null, but should be handled if nulls are allowed.

Comment: But what if I want to the same thing but now on per company basis. how can i do this

Comment: For that need to remove CID from where clause and put it in select and also group by CID.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the data is that the joins duplicate the rows.  A.UID=B.UID AND A.CID=B.CID links each row twice.

Try using unions as following

```
SELECT SUM(t.TotalQuantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount), SUM(t.TotalQuantity)/SUM(t.TotalAmount) FROM (
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, SUM(Quantity*Rate) AS TotalAmount
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity), 0
    FROM B 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity), SUM(Quantity*Rate)
    FROM C 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
) t
WHERE t.UID=1 AND t.CID=1
```

To have the data grouped by Company as asked in the comments:

```
SELECT t.CID, SUM(t.TotalQuantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount), SUM(t.TotalQuantity)/SUM(t.TotalAmount) FROM (
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, SUM(Quantity*Rate) AS TotalAmount
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity), 0
    FROM B 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CID, UID, SUM(Quantity), SUM(Quantity*Rate)
    FROM C 
    GROUP BY CID, UID
) t
WHERE t.UID=1
GROUP BY t.CID
```

Comment: same problem, its adding every thing twice! e.g if i have A.Quantity=100, its adding 200+B.Quantity

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: True, I wanted to keep the format of the original post for clarity. Will use proper syntax next time.

Comment: @user2516394 Are you sure the tables are joined correctly?  If you are missing a key field in the join, it might double the rows.

Comment: I've only UserId, CompanyId & Quantity Field in Table B

Comment: @user2516394 Join with table B should be fine then. What about tables A and C?  We are probably missing a join there.

Comment: But what if I want to the same thing but now on per company basis. how can i do this